# Freetype - new line offset is too big

Tags: c++, freetype2

I am calculating line offset as:

```
int size = 16;
int dpi = 260;

FT_Select_Charmap(ff, FT_ENCODING_UNICODE);
if (FT_Set_Char_Size(ff, 0, size * 64, dpi, dpi)){
    return;
}
int newLineOffset = static_cast<int>(ff->size->metrics.height / 64);
```

For *Arial*, this works fine. However, when I load *Google Noto*, line offset is to big. Should I use something else?

Comment: What is a line offset? And how do you know it is to big?

Comment: Freetype height property is "a value the designer of the font finds appropriate", so I doubt it's "wrong" as such.